# How to change the size of the menu content

Tags: ios, swiftui

```swift
Menu {
    Button("one", action: {print("one")})
    Button("two", action: {print("two")})
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
}
```

It looks like this
[image]

How to change the width of the menu content?

Comment: It would be very hard to change. That's a system UI, so usually either just go with it, or make your own.

Comment: one dirty hack is to put a lot of blank spaces: `Button("one                             ", action: {print("one")})`